# Communicating with WebAssign calcpad in TWebbrowser and EmbeddedWB

Tags: flash, delphi, browser, web, axshockwaveflash

So I've been making my own browser in delphi 2009 getting used to it, and i've come across a problem.  webassign.net has these questions that use calcpad or mathpad or physpad (all the same/ex http://www.webassign.net/manual/student_guide/t_s_answering_calcpad.htm) to answer homework questions.  While using TWebbrowser, i can see the box where i put my answer but i cant interact with it.  Also I get script errors of sorts like "error in-http://www.webassign.net/wastatic/wacachef033ab37c30201f73f142449d037028d/pads/js/pad.js do you want to continue running scripts on this page?"  When i use EmbeddedWB I don't get the script errors but the same problem is still there, I can't interact with box in which i need to put my answers.   Here is an example of the boxes.

```
   <object width="110" height="40" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="calcpad_obj_RQ_1255772_0_0_1255827" name="calcpad_obj_RQ_1255772_0_0_1255827" data="/v4swf/calcpad/calcpad-1.11.swf"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="flashvars" value="padid=RQ_1255772_0_0_1255827&amp;xml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%3Cp%20v%3D%221.0%22%3E%3Cme%3E%3Cabs%3E%3Ca%3E%3C/a%3E%3C/abs%3E%3C/me%3E%3C/p%3E&amp;enabled=1&amp;showresp=1"></object>
```

http://www.webassign.net/v4swf/calcpad/calcpad-1.11.swf

There is a good example of what Im having problems with.  Going to that site in the delphi browser i can enter in things but that changes when i get to the real assignment.

I really am clueless as to whats happening that i can't use the box.

Comment: I see that this question is tagged a Java question, but where does Java come into play here?

Comment: ah thanks for that catch, I meant to put flash!

Comment: Have you tried your code in standalone Internet Explorer ? I'm satisfied Firefox user thus my IE has no updates for Flash plugin for instance. I haven't tried your code but this would be the first I would test.